# Extjs 3.4 Tree Grid default sort by a specified column

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm using ExtJs 3.4 and I have a `TreeGrid (Ext.ux.tree.TreeGrid)` with a column model.

The sorting works very well with the data brought by a `TreeGridLoader` when you click on every column's header, but I want to `sort by a default specified column`.
Is there a way to achieve that? I want to specify that, like I said I don't have a store, instead I have a TreeGridLoader defined.

UPDATE

Thanks to `wes` the best(and general) solution for my problem would be:

```
 // simulate click on order number and order by this column
var treeGrid = Ext.getCmp('siteStructureGrid');
var index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i<treeGrid.columns.length; i++){
    if (treeGrid.columns[i].id == 'orderNumberColumn'){
        index = i;
    }
}
var column = treeGrid.columns[index];
treeGrid.fireEvent('headerClick', column);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method may be to call the header's click handler. Normally I'd frown on that, but it's handling a bunch of tasks rather than calling a single public sort method. IMO the TreeGrid UX isn't very well fleshed out.

```
// grab the column and fire the click, since it works for you
var column = treeGrid.columns[index];
treeGrid.fireEvent('headerClick', column);
```

Comment: Yes it's a fine method and it works...it's somehow hard coded but it works (at least until I find another solution)...Thanks! Also it would be better if it would be a way to get the column index by id in a tree grid instead every time I add another column I have to be careful to increment the index of the sorted column

Comment: I think that's a sad consequence of the `TreeGrid` extending from `TreePanel` and not `GridPanel`. You don't get any of the column handling convenience like `getColumnByID`. Lacking a proper multi-inheritance model, it was probably just too much work for them to add to an unsupported extension.

Comment: Yea I saw that TreeGrid extends TreePanel, sadly... I've updated my question with the most general solution by using `treeGrid.columns[i].id` to find the index of my column id. Thanks!